# javascript validation for special character's index/position

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have input as 23 digit key from input box which will be separated by '-'.

E.g: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX

This is expected format means, 5 digit followed by -(hyphen).

Problem:
User can input any data/wrong format, like XXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXX, in this case index of hyphen is invalid. How can I valided the index of hyphen?

I tried:

```
  if((prd_len==23) && (n!=-1))
  {
       var indices = [];
        for(var i=0; i<prd_id.length;i++) 
        {
           if (prd_id[i] === "-")
               { 
                   indices.push(i); 
               }
        }

        for(var x=0;x<indices.length;x++)
        {
           if((indices[x]!=5) || (indices[x]!=11) || (indices[x]!=17))
           {
             $('#msgErr1').text('Please enter valid key.');
             flag=1;
           }
        }
 }
```

where prd_len=length of the accepted input from user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try regular expressions

```
if(input.match(/^(\d{5}-){3}\d{5}$/))
    everything is OK
```

This expression basically reads "five digits and a dash - three times, then five digits". For further reference see

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @Emma: then replace `\d` with a range of appropriate chars, like `[0-9A-Z]`.

Answer (score 2):

As `thg435` said, but more human-readable :-)

```
var correct = input.match(/^\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\d$)
```